# Is there any way to restrict the use of tags and filters in Django templates?

Tags: python, django, templates

I know Django has already a good templating system for designers but I wonder if it is possible to limit the usage of certain template tags and filters.

We are building a Django plugin for designers to make template developing more open, but we want to hide some logic of django template system and expose just the necessary to the designer.

In example: How can I prevent the use of `{% load %}` template tag and preload only the tags that I want?

Comment: Approximately how many tags do you want to disable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this decorator: [Safe template decorator](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2750/)

From author description:

> A decorator that restricts the tags and filters available to template
>   loading and parsing within a function.
>
> This is mainly meant to be used when granting users the power of the
>   DTL. You obviously don't want users to be able to do things that could
>   be potentially malicious.
>
> The {% ssi %} tag, for example, could be used to display sensitive
>   data if improperly configured.
>
> {% load %} gives them access to all the unlimited python code you
>   wrote in your templatetags. {% load sudo %}{% sudo rm -rf / %} o_0
>
> Note that the "load" tag (among others) is not listed in the default
>   tag whitelist. If you parse a template (however indirectly) in a
>   function decorated with this, unlisted builtin tags will behave like
>   undefined tags (ie, they will result in a TemplateSyntaxError).
>
> Since {% load %} is not whitelisted, you may want to include some
>   custom tags or filters as "builtins" for convenience. Simply put the
>   module paths to the libraries to include in the extra kwarg or the
>   extra_libraries list. Generally, this is not recommended, as these
>   libraries need to be carefully and defensively programmed.
>
> NOTE: This does not do anything about cleaning your rendering context!
>   That's completely up to you! This merely restricts what tags and
>   filters are allowed in the templates.

Examples:

```
from django.template.loader import get_template
safe_get_template = use_safe_templates(get_template)
tmpl = safe_get_template('myapp/some_template.html')

from django.template import Template
use_safe_templates(Template)('{% load sudo %}')
# TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag 'load'
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way would be to implement your own [template loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loader-types) similar to [Django's file system loader](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/loaders/filesystem.py) and strip certain tags out of the text (guess you could event turn into a template/template nodes when doing so to be able to parse it correctly) before giving the template to Django for further processing.